# UIcollection view crashes when i change the number of items in data Source

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
 self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false

        self.collectionView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.collectionView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)//CGSizeMake(0, 1)
        self.collectionView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.collectionView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        self.collectionView.clipsToBounds = false
        self.collectionView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

this is what i did with collection view in didLoad

now the problem is when i set my data source array lets say

```
var myDataSource:[Custom Model] = []
```

when i change  myDataSourceArray it has 10 values initially after changes this array got only 1 value now when i reload collection view it gives this...

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.54.4/UICollectionViewData.m:435
2018-10-29 12:28:27.884302+0500 MyBetterDealsv2[14203:147469] Task <A3EE0E68-F980-47FD-A5B2-941C1D233A34>.<7> finished with error - code: -1001
2018-10-29 12:28:27.904908+0500 MyBetterDealsv2[14203:145748] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}'
```

i tried invalidate layout also but it gives same error didnt get the solution yet :(

below are my delegate methods for collectionview

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(self.myallDeals != nil && self.myallDeals?.count != 0){
        self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 220
    }
    return self.myallDeals?.count ?? 0

}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dealCell", for: indexPath ) as! DealsCell
    let cellData = self.myallDeals?[indexPath.row]
    cell.dealTitle.text = cellData?.dealTitle
    cell.dealDescription.text = cellData?.dealLocation
    cell.discount.text = "$\(cellData?.discountedPrice ?? "") now"
    cell.dealDistanceLabel.text = "\(cellData?.distance ?? 0.0) km away"
    cell.ratingView.rating = cellData?.averageRating ?? 0.0

    cell.dealImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: cellData?.dealPicture ?? ""), placeholderImage: nil)
    if(cellData?.isliked == true){
        cell.likeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 106/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: .normal)
    }else{
         cell.likeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:255, green: 255, blue:255, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .normal)
    }

    //===========================
    return cell
}


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // handle tap event
            if(Constants.isGuestUser){
                self.present(Utilities.SelectionButtonActionSheet(), animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{
                let deal = self.myallDeals?[indexPath.row]
                //dealdetail
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dealdetail") as! DealDetailVC
                vc.mydeal = deal
                Utilities.animationOnPush(sender: self, nxtVC: vc)
                print("You selected cell.")
            }

        }
```

[image]

this is the orignal cell

this is what i got using sateesh code

[image]

Comment: Is your collectionView layout customized ?

Comment: Can you post your delegates methods?

Comment: @Sateesh no i im using flow  from storyboard just no customization applied

Comment: @nikhilgohil11 yes offcourse

Comment: @nikhilgohil11 just updated question with delegate methods plz have a look

Comment: `UICollectionView` uses `IndexPath` with `item` instead of `row`. You are using `row` in `let cellData = self.myallDeals?[indexPath.row]`

Comment: at first run it works fine when i change the alldeals array it crashes..

Comment: @RickyMo i just tried item instead of row it produces same crash

Comment: Can you show the lines where you change the data, reload and crash?

Comment: @RickyMo
self.myallDeals = allDeals
 var myallDeals:[Deal]?{
        didSet{
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            
        }
    }

this is how i change and reload

Comment: Have tried to reload data on main thread. var myallDeals:[Deal]? {
    didSet{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Sateesh the problem is when if the count of array is grater or equal to the previous count it works fine if the new count is less than previous count it crashes with above error

Comment: @Sateesh same crash with main queue :(

Comment: Try to reset the layout: 
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = //.horizontal or .vertical
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout

Comment: @junaid where you change the dataSource array?

Comment: @VDPurohit first i fetch deals acoording to my current loc when user draws route i change the dataSource array

Comment: @Sateesh it solved problem but the cells are not same as i designed in story board ;(

Comment: @junaid can you please upload image what you got after add the Sateesh's code and before it which exactly what you want?

Comment: @VDPurohit im just adding images see

Comment: thanks, @junaid I saw accepted answer below. Happy that you found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help you

```
let layOut = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layOut.layout.scrollDirection = //.horizontal or .vertical
self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layOut
```

And use below delegate method of "UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout"

```
extension yourViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // your code here
        //width and height as per your requirement
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame,size.width - 24, height: height)
    }
}
```